# Problem regarding Arduino & GSM module kit

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the following program to receive messages from a GSM module.

As we start our kit, we received two messages "*main door is open*" and "*store room is open*". (Depending upon sensor position)

This program is run properly, but the problem is that it repeats the message after some time. It does not depend on time.

Suppose our store room is closed. I receive this message on my given mobile number, but after some time two "*the store room is open*" messages are received and after this message immediately the message "*received store room is closed*". (means it sets sensor to its initial mode i.e. closed) Same problem is happening with this main door.

My kit contains an Arduino UNO board, GSM module SIM800 and two limit switches (one for the main door and second is for the store room)

I keep my both sensor and Arduino board distance over 17 meters by using CAT5e cable.

My code:

```cpp
const int Main = 7;  // pin define for main door sensor
const int Store = 8; // pin define for store room sensor
const int Main_led =  13;  // indication for main door sensor
const int Store_led =  14;  // indication for store room sensor

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Main_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Store_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Main, INPUT);
  pinMode(Store, INPUT);
}

void sendMessage(char *text) {
    Serial.println("OK");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91-------------");
    Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print(text);
    Serial.write(0x1A);
    delay(5000);
}

void loop() {
  static int oldState1 = -1;
  static int oldState2 = -1;

  int buttonState1 = digitalRead(Main);
  if (buttonState1 != oldState1) {
    digitalWrite(Main_led, buttonState1);
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH)
      sendMessage("Main Door is closed");
    else
      sendMessage("Main Door is open");
    oldState1 = buttonState1;
  }

  int buttonState2 = digitalRead(Store);
  if (buttonState2 != oldState2) {
    digitalWrite(Store_led, buttonState2 );
    if (buttonState2 == HIGH)
      sendMessage("Store room is closed");
    else
      sendMessage("Store room is open");
    oldState2 = buttonState2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the LEDs reflect the messages when you get these odd messages?  It sounds like there is a "glitch" in the sensor data, the equivalent of a switch bouncing, if so add some de-bouncing code.  When a sensor reports a change in state, wait one second (ish) before reporting the change in state.